# Getting URL as a parameter in Flask - but Flask stripping out the params from the URL

Tags: python, flask

I am passing in a URL as a parameter

GET `http://127.0.0.1:5000/?url=https://url.com/?param1=123&param2=456`

When I grab the URL parameter with `request.args.get('url')` the value returned is `https://url.com/?param1=123` so its stripping off the second parameter in the URL

How can I get all parameters?

Comment: you need use `from urllib import urlencode` encode your url

Comment: If it's possible, I think you'd want to URIencode that url param. Is that an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode your url, like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/?url=https%3A%2F%2Furl.com%2F%3Fparam1%3D123%26param2%3D456
```

use python3

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode

get_url = '?'.join(['http://127.0.0.1:5000/', urlencode({'url': 'https://url.com/?param1=123&param2=456'})])
```